# TypeError: 'node' object is not callable

Tags: python, object, tree, typeerror, callable

I am getting an error (`TypeError: 'node' object is not callable`) when I try to get my previous node. What am I doing wrong?

My Node Class:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.node=[]
        self.info = None
        self.prev = None
        self.depth=-1
        self.step = []
    def prev(self):
        return self.prev
    def add(self):
        node1=node()
        self.node.append(node1)
        node1.prev=self
        return node1
```

My Code accessing `prev` (`last_node` should have a depth value of around 5):

```
rev = last_node
dep = rev.depth
revPath = [None]*(dep*4)
for g in range(0,dep):
    revPath[dep - (g*4) - 1] = rev.step[3]
    revPath[dep - (g*4) - 2] = rev.step[2]
    revPath[dep - (g*4) - 3] = rev.step[1]
    revPath[dep - (g*4) - 4] = rev.step[0]
    rev = rev.prev()
```

Additional info:

I am trying to traverse the tree backwards in order to see the path that was taken. The `step[]` value just grabs a few integers. The code also runs fine with everything except `prev` (i.e. If I take out the part to find the path taken, there is no issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined a method called `prev` in your class, but in your constructor you assign `None` to `self.prev`, and then later in `add` you assign to it again with a `node` instance.

Therefore, when you try to invoke `rev.prev()`, the method has been over-written and you're in fact trying to call a `node` object, hence the error.

It's conventional in Python (see [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)) to prefix private fields (those that client code is not supposed to use) with an underscore, like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._node=[]
    self._prev = None
    # Etc.
```

It's also risky to name your class in lower case, since any variable named `node` will shadow it and make it inaccessible.  The convention in Python is to use Pascal casing (starting with a capital) for class names (see [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) again).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I didn't realize that making it private could make or break something that seems like it should be so simple. I guess I should read up more on how the classes should work.

Comment: @Upgrayded Python has no explicit notion of private members; it's simply conventional to use a leading underscore to denote "privacy".  This has the added advantage of mitigating name clashes like you've experienced here.